# Limit backorder qty of the product

Tags: stock, ee-1.13.1.0, backorder

[This question was already asked](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/limit-product-backorder-qty), but I want to know is there some issue if I use following solution to limit the backorder qty:
I'll set "`Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock`" as negative number on Inventory tab of product edit page and re-assign this negative number via `catalog_product_prepare_save` observer. Thanks.

Comment: Extension is available http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sb-backorder-qty-limiter.html

Answer (score 2):

Crazy timing - I had this problem today too!

I had opted for a similar solution when I found your question. I did some more digging to see what the root cause of this issue is:

- Magento 1.7 CE/1.12 EE introduced this change.
- `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php` contains a function `_filterStockData` that sets negative values of `min_qty` to 0:

```
protected function _filterStockData(&$stockData)
{
  if (is_null($stockData)) {
      return;
  }
  if (!isset($stockData['use_config_manage_stock'])) {
      $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
  }
  if (isset($stockData['qty']) && (float)$stockData['qty'] > self::MAX_QTY_VALUE) {
      $stockData['qty'] = self::MAX_QTY_VALUE;
  }
  if (isset($stockData['min_qty']) && (int)$stockData['min_qty'] < 0) {
      $stockData['min_qty'] = 0;
  }
  if (!isset($stockData['is_decimal_divided']) || $stockData['is_qty_decimal'] == 0) {
      $stockData['is_decimal_divided'] = 0;
  }
}
```

- The line in the 1.7.0.0 release notes for this is `Fixed: "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" option works incorrect`.
- There is a similar function in the code for updating stock via the REST API.
- There is a thread on the defunct [magento boards about this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/288259/), a poster mentions a bug report that was accepted to be fixed. I can't find any bug report. This still exists in 1.9 CE and 1.14 EE.
- This behaviour [exists in magento2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/c8b7223139366e8030b0b8ae43406495e46ec95e/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/StockDataFilter.php#L69).

I decided to override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` controller to create a `_filterStockData` function without the replacement of `min_qty`.

I wrote an extension to handle this and have put it up on Github here: https://github.com/etailer/etailer_backorders

I've not run in to any issues with negative values of `min_qty` yet.

**Update:**
Allowing negative `min_qty` doesn't limit the number of backorders that can be added to cart or sold. It also doesn't move products to `out_of_stock` when `qty` = `min_qty`.

However I've added both these features to my extension so you can refer to that if you're after implementation ideas!