# Best approach to limit the backorder Qty in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, cart, stock, backorder

This question or similar have been asked in [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/limit-product-backorder-qty) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41300/limit-backorder-qty-of-the-product) nevertheless none of the provided answers offer the result I am trying to achieve.

Lets say you want to limit the backorder qty.

You create an extra product attribute where you store the maximum quantity allowed for backorders.

So if a product has `qty` 10 and `backorder_limit` 5 you want a customer to be able to add to the cart and buy 15 but showing the message:

> *"We don't have as many "xxxx" as you requested, but we'll back order the remaining 5."*

If the customer try to add 1 or more to the cart you want to prevent this and show the message:

> *We don't have as many "xxxx" as you requested.*

and prevent the extra qty to be added to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have solved the issue as follow:

- I created and extra product attribute to specify `backorder_limit`.
- Then, I used a plugin in
  `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator\Initializer\StockItem`
  to intercept and hook around the `Initialize` method in `StockItem`
  class.

There I limited the quoteItem qty to `MaxAllowedQty`.

```
/**
 * @param StockStateProvider $subject
 * @param callable           $proceed
 * @param Item               $stockItem
 * @param QuoteItem          $quoteItem
 * @param int                $qty
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
 *
 */
public function aroundInitialize($subject, callable $proceed, $stockItem, $quoteItem, $qty)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject $result */
    $result = $proceed($stockItem, $quoteItem, $qty);

    if ($stockItem->getBackorders()) {
        if ($this->getMaxAllowedQty($stockItem, $quoteItem) - $result->getData('orig_qty') < 0) {

            $quoteItem->setData('qty', $this->getMaxAllowedQty($stockItem, $quoteItem));

            $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                __('Quantity was recalculated from %1 to %2', $result->getData('orig_qty'), $this->getMaxAllowedQty($stockItem, $quoteItem)));

        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Is this not exactly how the OUt of Stock THreshold setting works? https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html#out-of-stock-threshold